# Difference between RenderBody and RenderSection

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

In ***MVC/Razor*** syntax, I'm trying to understand why we need `@RenderBody`.

For example (code taken from [example](http://blog.overridethis.com/blog/post/2010/11/13/Learning-Razor-Shared-Content-Layout.aspx))

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>My WebSite</title>
        <style>
            #container { width: 700px; }
            #left { float: left; width: 150px; }
            #content { padding: 0 210px 0 160px; }
            #right { float: right; width: 200px; }
            .clear { clear: both; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="left">
                @RenderSection("left", required:false)
            </div>
            <div id="content">
                @RenderBody()
            </div>
            <div id="right">
                @RenderSection("right", required:false)
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>


@{
      Layout = "~/_3ColLayout.cshtml";
}

<h1>Main Content</h1>

@section left {
    <h1>Left Content</h1>
}

@section right {
    <h1>Right Content</h1>
}
```

Why can't I simply use `@RenderSection` for everything, like this:

```
<div id="content">
     @RenderSection("Body", required:true)
</div>

@section Body{
    <h1>Body Content</h1>
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simply because of convenience. Rendering the body is something that you would most likely do so its good to have a dedicated function for that. Keeps you from declaring a @section for the body and gives an easier to call function.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that RenderBody's role was only for a matter of convenience.

Answer (score 15):

Start with `@RenderBody`, this is vital. Your _layout has to have it. This is where your view will be rendered. If you leave it out, your app will die (I think on run time, as Views are not compiled).

[**Correction:**
Without Renderbody, the View referencing this particular layout will die on run-time. (Important to note that layout are themselves optional.)]

Sections are code blocks defined within your View with similar names

@RenderSection("Navbar", required: false)

could have a corresponding code block in your View.

```
@section Navbar{
    <!-- Content Here -->
}
```

I emphasize ***could*** because the Navbar is delcared `required: false`

Sections are a way each View can share a piece of functionality / markup with the _layout.

**Followup:**
In my modest time of MVC development I have learned to make modest use of sections.

- Sections are useful for making sure your JS references are placed in your HTML  section (even though this is an antiquated practice.
- Sections are useful for top and side navs
- Sections **never** be required. To do so makes your code fragile!

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I was wondering why RenderBody was included in the framework to start with, when RenderSection could simply be used instead.  However, as @Basarat Ali mentioned, it seems like it was added for convenience.

Comment: this was a good question. Not enough attention is paid to it.

Comment: Possible that this was not always the case, but @RenderBody() is not actually required. AS mentioned in other responses, it is useful for convenience as well as a defaulting convention.

Comment: @bingles, have you created a layout page without RenderBody()?

Answer (score 1):

`RenderBody` is required, as it's what renders each view. `RenderSection` has an optional parameter that lets you mark the section as not required.

Comment: Thanks, my question though was why can't RenderSection be used for the body as well--why do we need another directive...the body is after all a section of the page.

Comment: Seems like that would just add more overhead to each view, since everything would have to exist in one section or another, much like WebForms pages that used master pages needed to have all their content in a contentplaceholder or three. I personally prefer the implied body section.

Answer (score 0):

[here](https://devbloggies.blogspot.com/2019/07/renderbody-and-renderpage-in-mvc.html) is basic information about the RenderBody() and RenderPage().